# Wrong Format in assigning Json Datetime to TextBoxFor in MVC

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, razor

I have a function that will set the update datetime in a textbox, based on the changing of a dropdown .

My Jquery :

```
function ModifymyDiv (element) {

    var option = $("#myDiv option:selected").text();
    var requrl = '@Url.Action("PopulateConfirmationFields", "Controller", null, Request.Url.Scheme, null)';
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: requrl,

        success: function (data) {

            $('#txtconfTime').empty();
            $('#txtconfName').empty();
            $('#txtconfName').val(data.name);
            $('#txtconfTime').val(data.time);
        },
        error: function (failure) {
        }
    });
}
```

My Json Method :

```
 public ActionResult PopulateConfirmationFields()
        {
            User usr = userProxy.GetUserById(UserAppContext.UserOID);
            string name = string.Format("{1},{0}", usr.FirstName, usr.LastName);
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            var t = new { name = name, time = time };
            return Json(t, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Still in my TextBox ...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.confirmationDateTime, new { id = "txtconfTime" })
```

the DateTime value looks something like ...

```
/Date(1348040819674)/
```

How can I pass the correct Datetime Format to my TextBox ? 
P.S. Modifying it into string is not an option in this particular case.

Comment: This is json date formating, one option you my apply is to pass as a string in your json method.

Answer (score 1):

For example you could:

```
public ActionResult PopulateConfirmationFields()
        {
            User usr = userProxy.GetUserById(UserAppContext.UserOID);
            string name = string.Format("{1},{0}", usr.FirstName, usr.LastName);
            String time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            var t = new { name = name, time = time };
            return Json(t, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ... but my last P.s. states: " P.S. Modifying it into string is not an option in this particular case. "

Comment: I am sorry, I missed it. However I know it is not elegant but it was the faster way I found to fix a similar problem. If you use the date in your view to populate a textbox which contains text anyway... Again sorry for the crap reply :)

Comment: Np .. thats how I usually skipped the issue.Look at my solution below. It actually works

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution :

```
        var jsonDate= data.time;
        var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
        var curr_date = date.getDate();
        var curr_month = date.getMonth();
        curr_month++; //January is represented by 0 
        var curr_year = date.getFullYear();
        var date =curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year;
            $('#txtconfTime').empty();
            $('#txtconfName').empty();
            $('#txtconfName').val(data.name);
            $('#txtconfTime').val(date);
        },
```